# Can't build a xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I am using xamarin with visual studio 2015, and when I create a new cross platform project and try to build it, this error shows up.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Reason: C:\Users\US\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip is not a valid zip file App2.Droid
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a bug with downloaded ressources, do this actions and comes back to us if your problem persist :

- Navigate to C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
- Delete 96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip file from the folder.
- Delete /.bin & /.obj folders from your project location.
- Clean and Rebuild your project.